# Copying databases between sql servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am developing a Web Application for copying data between SQL Servers.  The tool will let you specify which server you are copying from/to and will then copy a specific database (which always has the same name) from the source server to the destination server.

What is the best method to do this? The data could be quite large, so speed needs to be taken into account also.

---

My attempt at this is to try to run an SSIS package that I created using SQL Server Management Studio. The package is stored locally.

The plan is to modify the Source and Destination connection strings and kick off the package.

This is my code for doing so:

```
public void DataTransfer(String sourceConnection, String destConnection, String pkgLocation)
{
        Package pkg;
        Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;

        try
        {
            app = new Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

            foreach (ConnectionManager connectionManager in pkg.Connections)
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder;
                switch (connectionManager.Name)
                {
                    case "SourceConnection":
                        builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(sourceConnection);
                        builder.Remove("Initial Catalog");
                        builder.Add("Initial Catalog", "StagingArea");
                        var sourceCon = builder.ConnectionString + ";Provider=SQLNCLI;Auto Translate=false;";
                        //Added spaces to retain password!!!
                        sourceCon = sourceCon.Replace(";", "; ");
                        connectionManager.ConnectionString = sourceCon;
                        Debug.WriteLine(connectionManager.ConnectionString.ToString());
                        break;
                    case "DestinationConnection":
                        builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(destConnection);
                        builder.Remove("Initial Catalog");
                        builder.Add("Initial Catalog", "StagingArea");
                        var destCon = builder.ConnectionString + ";Provider=SQLNCLI;Auto Translate=false;";
                        //Added spaces to retain password!!!
                        destCon = destCon.Replace(";", "; ");
                        connectionManager.ConnectionString = destCon;
                        Debug.WriteLine(connectionManager.ConnectionString.ToString());
                        break;
                }
            }
            pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(pkgResults.ToString());
}
```

When `pkg` is executed I get the following exceptions:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsComponentException' occurred in Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here, any ideas?

Comment: what have you tried so far? what problems have you encountered? have you considered pre-existing options like SSIS?

Comment: take a look at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Database+Mirroring/66357/

Comment: I would like to use SSIS if possible. I'm guessing the server would need to have Integration Services installed? I've looked at SSIS and the bcp utility so far...

Comment: @Marc Gravell Please see above for my method and attempt at performing this task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write an [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) package to do the data copying / transformation and the website would simply configure the connection string and kick off the package.

Comment: Would this work with one SSIS package? I'd only have to change the connection string, or would the package itself need modifying?

Comment: Yes you could write a single package for this.  Your web app could simply configure the connection strings externally.  So make your package read its connections from a db or file and the web app can just write to the configuration source

Comment: Can I achieve the same thing with the SSIS package that SQL Management Studio creates? I saved it last time I did an export, if I include this in my solution can I modify the connection strings and run it?

Comment: I've updated the description with my attempt at doing this, any idea why it's not working?

Comment: This is working now, there was a problem with the connection strings.